# Discs burned in Windows have different language filenames in Ubuntu

Tags: backup, language-support, filename

I've browsed these backups before and not had an issue with them [other than the rate a disc spins up, if at all], but now they're all given Chinese character filenames - it's probably a simple thing, but I'm not seeing it in terms of redressing the matter for normal access, any pointers?

Comment: "I'm not seeing it in terms of redressing the matter for normal access" — what does this part mean?

Answer (score 0):

It means, all the answers that are out there do not correlate with the question I'm asking, like it simply doesn't exist as a known issue [yet].

**UPDATE**
[& for future reference]  I rebooted and the matter appears resolved - still cannot imagine how or why that would be, so it's resolved in one sense - just that there's no explanation or reasoning behind the occurrence - it happened 'in session', previous discs had loaded fine, then it occurred.  An update did nothing to remedy it.  A reboot resolved it, but nothing to indicate what happened comes to light from this action.